# Как взять строку из файла?

Tags: php

Есть обычный текстовый документ count.txt. В нем записано число 10. Как с помощью PHP достать из файла число, прибавить к нему произвольное число в диапазоне от 0,1 до 0,6 и переписать файл (заменить 10 на получившееся число)?

Comment: так `trim(file_get_contents('count.txt'))`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать таким образом, только если у вас в файле хранится только это одно число.

```
<?php
// открываем файл и считываем число строкой
$f = fopen("input.txt", "r"); 
$num = fgets($f); 
// переводим строку в число
var_dump($num); 
$num= (int)$num;
var_dump($num);
// прибавляем случайное число из диапазона [0.1,0.6]
$res = $num + rand(0.1, 0.6); 
fclose($f);
// переоткрываем файл на запись с предварительной очисткой
$f = fopen("input.txt", "w+b");
// записываем результат в файл
fwrite($f,$res);
fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: Ваш код ошибку выдает

Comment: @ВикторПавлов какую именно?

Comment: Вы уже исправили :-) f забыли к write приписать. А вот функция rand() для десятичных чисел всегда возвращает 0.

Comment: А если у нас в файле не 10, а 10,54. Тогда как преобразовать строку в число? Ведь int - это целое число.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов для этого просто замените (int) на (float)

Answer (score 0):

### ООП стиль

```
$add = 0.1;

$file = new SplFileObject("file.txt", 'r+');

if (!$file->flock(LOCK_EX)) { //блокировка файла
    throw new Exception("Не удалось получить блокировку!");
} 

$number = $file->fread($file->getSize()); //читаем содержимое
$number = (float) $number + $add; //складываем 
$file->ftruncate(0); //обрезаем файл до 0 длины
$file->rewind(); //перемещаемся к началу файла
$file->fwrite($number); //записываем число
$file->flock(LOCK_UN);   // снимаем блокировку 
$file = null; //close file
```

### Решение в одну строку

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', (float) file_get_contents('file.txt')+0.1,  LOCK_EX);
```

Здесь не учитывается блокировка при чтении файла, если скрипт выполняется в несколько потоков, могут возникнуть проблемы.

---

*Также можно через обычные функции (fopen, fwrite), но примеров в интернете с этим решением тьма, поэтому описывать не буду*. Первый вариант безопаснее для многопоточной записи, второй вариант проще.